# Tableau cuts off fields in table

Tags: tableau-api

In Tableau, I have a table with 8 Dimensions in the Rows Shelf.  I also have a Calculated Field Dimension called "Blank" which only contains whitespace (" ") as a placeholder.  However, as shown in the image below, this table is only displaying Fields 3-8 despite Fields 1-8 being included in the Rows Shelf.  How can I fix this? I have edited the photo to redact sensitive information, yet included field names so it conveys the necessary information.

[image: Tableau Image]

Comment: At the top go to `Analysis` > `Table Layout` > `Advanced` the increase the number of columns from 6 to 8 or more.

Comment: @Nicarus: Thanks, that worked perfectly!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For the sake of others that may stumble upon this question.

The reason the columns are not shown is due a Tableau setting that is defaulting the maximum number of visible "row labels" to 6. This setting can be changed easily.

---

**Problem** - Column labels hidden and labels concatenated:

[image]

---

**Solution** - Update the table layout settings:

At the top, click on `Analysis` > `Table Layout` > `Advanced`

[image]

Increase `Maximum levels of row labels` and `Maximum levels of horizontal row labels` to at least the number of dimensions in the `Rows` section.

[image]

---

**Result** - All column labels displayed:

[image]